# Merge and Save model in tensorflow.js after training in browser

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I am following a tensorflow.js [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-teachablemachine-codelab/index.html#6), in which I am loading a mobilenet as a backbone

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load the latest version of TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/mobilenet"></script>
  </head>
```

and in js it is called as `net`

```
 net = await mobilenet.load();
```

Then the tutorial continuous by adding a "K-Nearest Neighbors Classifier"-Layer

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/knn-classifier"></script>
```

and later call it by `classifier`

```
const classifier = knnClassifier.create();
```

after then adding samples to the Classifier, for making predictions the whole pipeline has to be inferred

```
// Get the activation from mobilenet.
const activation = net.infer(img, 'conv_preds');
// Then feed the activation to the custom output layer
const result = await classifier.predictClass(activation);
```

Now I want to download the whole model (`net` + `classifier`) as a .hdf file or similar. How do I do this? Do I still have to merge these two?

I know the `model.save` functionalities within python tensorflow and keras, but am lost as to how this is best done in tensorflow.js

**Update - Currently I am trying something along the lines of**

```
  // merging the model and then downloading it
  const merge_models = async (backbone, outputlayer) => {
      console.log('Downloading your model..');
    const model = tf.sequential();
    model.add(backbone);
    model.add(outputlayer);
    
    // download
    await model.save('downloads://my-model');
    console.log('..is completed.');
  };
```

but I am getting an error in the add function

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Comment: Currently trying to make sense out of this documentation. https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load#local_storage_browser_only so far no success.